# How to connect wordpress database with JAVA ? (mysql)

Tags: java, mysql, database, wordpress

I dont know much about the connection proccess i'm trying to connect wordpress database without creating new database with `my remotedesktop IP` in mysql. Normally i can connect localhost and i can connect to database that created with `remote ip`. In my server mydatabase `host name/Ip adress` is `localhost`, as i said i dont know the whole connection between `url` request,`wp-config` file and `mysql`. I think i'm sending request with `url` to `wp-config` and it is connecting to my `localhost`. Anyway i want to connect to my remotedesktop's localhost with `JAVA` but i couldn't. Let me explain with code . Hope i could explain myself.

Thanks in advance.

Here are the codes :

**wp-config.php**

```
define('DB_NAME', 'mydbname');

define('DB_USER', 'mydbuser');

define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mydbpass');

define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
```

**My connection code :**

```
public class Dt_page {
    public static DataSource getDataSource(int server) {

    String database_driver = null;
    String database_adres = null;
    String dbuser = null;
    String dbpass = null;

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    switch (server) {

        case 1://profile server
            database_driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            database_adres = "jdbc:mysql://MY_REMOTE_DESKTOP_IP:3306/?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true";
            dbuser = "mydbuser";
            dbpass = "mydbpass";
    }

     try {
        Class.forName(database_driver);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Dt_page.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("user", dbuser);
    props.put("password", dbpass);
    props.put("autoReconnect", "true");
    props.put("autoReconnectForPools", "true");

    props.put("validationQuery", "SELECT 1 from dual;");
    props.put("testWhileIdle","true");

    connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(database_adres, props);

    GenericObjectPool connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool(null, 12, GenericObjectPool.WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW, 60*30, 12,true,true);
    GenericKeyedObjectPoolFactory keyedObjectPoolFactory = new GenericKeyedObjectPoolFactory(null);


    PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory =
            new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory,
            connectionPool,
            keyedObjectPoolFactory,
            "select 1",
            30,
            null,
            false,
              true);                                       

    PoolingDataSource dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(connectionPool);            
    return dataSource;
```

**And SQL**

```
  QueryRunner qr;
    qr = new QueryRunner(Dt_page.getDataSource(1));       
    try {
        List<Object[]> v = qr.query("Select meta_value from mydbname.wp_favorite", new ArrayListHandler());
         System.out.println(v.size());
        for (Object[] objects : v) {
            for (Object object : objects) {
                System.out.println(object);
            }
        }  
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();           
    }
}
}
```

**Error Log:**

```
  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1014)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2367)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2288)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:78)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1188)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.prepareConnection(AbstractQueryRunner.java:175)
at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:304)
at tazedizi.TazeDizi.main(TazeDizi.java:29)
 Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications    link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has  not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:355)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2461)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2306)
... 19 more
  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at  java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:305)
... 21 more
```

Comment: This example is far from complete (where is the return of getDataSource(...)??), and also what is the issue? Please let us know the error, the logs...

Comment: Thank you, i edited my question. please look again

Comment: are you replacing MY_REMOTE_DESKTOP_IP with the real ip right?

Comment: yes of course, e.g "217.23.23.44"

Comment: uhm difficult to say... is db up? is the port the standard one? check again user and password, try to simplify the code, use debug, use 127.0.0.1 if db is on your machine...

Comment: it is not on my machine. but i can connect my localhost and if i create database with `remote_ip` i can connect too. Still i dont want to do this i want to connect my `remote_desktop_localhost` with java like anyone who write url and connect my database with wordpress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54347/discussion-between-paolof76-and-user3583237).

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

1. Are you sure that your mysql server is configurated to listend on MY_REMOTE_DESKTOP_IP ?
2. Are you sure that your firewall (iptable...) allows connexion on MY_REMOTE_DESKTOP_IP on tpc port 3306 ?

Comment: thank you for your answer my firelwall is completly off, if i create database with `remotedesktop ip` in mysql, i can connect it, but it is very slow process, i checked it. for ex. if i change my wp-config `localhost` to `remote_ip`, it slows down the process too. i just want to connect to my `remote_desktop_localhost` like anyone who write "www.example.com" and connect my database with wordpress.

Comment: the stack trace clearly state that connection failed because the jdbc client couldn't reach the server.

Comment: thank you, yes I know i can see that, my problem is about accessing to the server:)